# Java Android - SwipeRefreshLayout ListView hides the last result

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

why my last row is hidden in listview?
Hello, why my last row is hidden in listview?
Hello, why my last row is hidden in listview?

I have changed the xml code 1000 times already and still can't fix it.

SwipeRefreshLayout work good.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd2ny.jpg)

fragment_list.xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp">
        </ListView>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/empty_list_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`

list_row.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:strokeWidth="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_list"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.SelectedCornerRadius"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/city"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />
                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/region"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2" />
                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_check_region"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/check_list" />
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/check_delete" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

I have no idea how to fix it -.-

Answer (score 0):

The ListView's height is MATCH_PARENT which constrains it to the height of its parent ViewGroup. You should always define the height of scrollable views like ListView as WRAP_CONTENT so that it can freely expand according to the number of children.
Also it might be a good idea for the parent LinearLayout to be anchored to the top of the RelativeLayout:
android:layout_alignParentTop="true".
Leaving views floating freely in RelativeLayouts may have surprising consequences.